# Why is MSBuild generating .tlog files into CMakeFiles/CompilerIdC, and how do I make it stop?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, msbuild, teamcity

I have a CMake project, and one of my builds is on Visual Studio, using MSBuild, on a TeamCity buildserver.

What I'm seeing is frequent failures when running `git clean -f -d -x` (a step TeamCity does by itself while initializing a build, as part of source checkout). The reason it fails is because `.tlog` files are being generated into my CMake build folder -- into CMake's internal `CompilerIdC` project, which CMake uses to identify the local C compiler.

**What are `.tlog` files for, and what triggers their creation?** I haven't found documentation for this.

I don't understand why they're appearing *after* CMake's run, and build, are already finished. I especially don't understand why they're being created more than fifteen minutes after all of `CompilerIdC`'s source and project files have been deleted.

### Details

The files are being generated into `${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/CMakeFiles/3.5.2/CompilerIdC/Debug/CompilerIdC.tlog` . They're all of the form `link-VCTIP.(read|write|delete).*.tlog`.

Here's the state of the folder for a build that failed on `git clean` and stopped at 08:41 (current as of 09:30):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  570 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.delete.1.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121 1422 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.delete.26.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121 7062 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.read.1.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  402 Jun 28 08:50 link-VCTIP.read.103.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  402 Jun 28 08:55 link-VCTIP.read.120.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  418 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.read.26.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  286 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.read.27.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  286 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.read.28.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  286 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.read.29.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  402 Jun 28 08:45 link-VCTIP.read.87.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  600 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.write.1.tlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 CI 197121  286 Jun 28 08:57 link-VCTIP.write.26.tlog
```

The build log looks like this:

```
[08:39:58][VCS Root: MyVCS] [D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\58a2d5637a76fb3e]: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clean -f -d -x
[08:41:26][VCS Root: MyVCS] warning: failed to remove build/Windows-x64-Release/: Directory not empty
[08:41:27]
[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clean -f -d -x' command failed.
stdout: Removing Artifacts/x64/
<snip>
Removing build/Windows-x64-Release/CMakeFiles
<snip>
stderr: warning: failed to remove build/Windows-x64-Release/: Directory not empty
```

### Version Info

The tools I'm using are:

- MSBuild 14.0
- CMake 3.5.2
- TeamCity Professional 9.1.7

Comment: `What could be generating these files?` - Have you tried to [google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=visual+studio+tlog+file)? Almost any reference says the files are created by MSBuild.

Comment: Whole that comment could be added to the question post. (Possibly, with slightly rewording).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What are `.tlog` files?

They're output by MSBuild's File Tracker, which wraps Visual C++ build executables (e.g. `cl.exe` and `link.exe`) to track which files it writes to and reads from. It records these file paths in the `.tlog` files in an intermediate directory, and relies on these to define how an incremental build should be constructed.

(Source: [*Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build*](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=WKNCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT475&lpg=PT475&dq=msbuild%20tlog%20files&source=bl&ots=44kEhQz8KZ&sig=P3vGK08wbwG-iPMaoC8zvTKahhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwishPfM2YLcAhXLRMAKHRy-CuoQ6AEIbTAH#v=onepage&q=msbuild%20tlog%20files&f=false), by Sayed Hashimi and William Bartholomew.)

### What triggers their creation?

Any use of MSBuild can trigger the creation or update of `.tlog` files.

### Why are these files appearing so late?

One of the processes that writes `.tlog` files is `vctip.exe`. In March 2018, Microsoft engineer Ian Bearman (owner of telemetry for VC++) [explained](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/18985093-visual-studio-build-tools-2017-option-to-disable):

> This small application is a background process that runs during the build and allows the VC++ tools to communicate with the VS Telemetry Service (also known as VS Experience Improvement Program). The application stays running after a build in case another build is started immediately to help speed up compilation.
>
> **I understand that the current timeout (approaching something like 15 minutes) is way too long.**

So, the answer is: a background process remains alive even after the build is concluded, in this case even after all relevent files are deleted, and continues attempting to write telemetry files to its directory.

### How do I solve this?

Bearman suggests [two solutions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/18985093-visual-studio-build-tools-2017-option-to-disable):

1. **Upgrade Visual Studio.**

   > Upcoming releases of Visual Studio (starting with VS 2017 15.7, now in preview) will shorten the time this stays running down to 15 seconds after the last build. Hopeful this will resolve any issues you have with this program staying running.

(I have not attempted the upgrade, so I cannot confirm that this fixes the problem. I also note with interest [an earlier bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57166/vctipexe-continues-creating-files-after-builds-end.html) of very much the same issue, which was answered with [a promise in March 2018](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57166/vctipexe-continues-creating-files-after-builds-end.html#) that the recent update had fixed the problem.)

2. **Manually kill `vctip.exe`.**

> In the meantime, to workaround this problem feel free to manually kill vctip.exe at any time. You can use the Windows command `taskkill /IM vctip.exe` to stop it immediately. This is always safe to do without fear of data-loss or corruption.

In my own specific case of TeamCity, this is easy to add as an additional buildstep to your build configuration, after MSBuild is finished -- running the script:

```
taskkill /IM vctip.exe /f >nul 2>&1
```

Note that this solution does make certain assumptions of your buildsystem, e.g. that it isn't running multiple builds at once. And be sure to document this well, because figuring out later where it came from will be a headscratcher...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the actual root cause fix item here might be:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/support/build-troubleshooting-guidance/

> MSBuild and /nodeReuse:false
>
> If you invoke MSBuild during your build, make sure to pass the argument /nodeReuse:false (short form /nr:false). Otherwise MSBuild process(es) will remain running after the build completes. The process(es) remain for some time in anticipation of a potential subsequent build.
>
> This feature of MSBuild can interfere with attempts to delete or move a directory – due to a conflict with the working directory of the MSBuild process(es).
>
> The MSBuild and Visual Studio Build tasks already add /nr:false to the arguments passed to MSBuild. However, if you invoke MSBuild from your own script, then you would need to specify the argument.

?
(which, if actually being the correct treatment here, would be
a much more precise treatment than
the uncertainty-workaround of needing to randomly kill random non-owned processes at random times)

Note that
if this is the root cause, then
this might need to be fixed in CMake generator source code (msbuild invocation[, conditionally/intelligently]), too...

Side note: I consider the mechanism of keeping a background process running for - gasp! - telemetry purposes in a rather lifetime-imprecise / uncontrolled manner (occupation of directories, ...), and this for supposedly precisely-controlled/-executed/-deterministic build processing, a rather questionable[/offensive] thing.

Comment: Oooh, thanks. I'll need to see if I can go back, recreate, and try this as a fix.